# text with quotes in html textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a text box on an html form that I set with a value from the server. But if the value contains an quotation mark, it breaks things. So I html encode it to produce the quote entity, but now this entity shows up in the text box on the page.

Comment: where do you get/set this value? Also have you tried escaping `\"`

Comment: in this case, im passing a string through the viewbag and setting it in the view.

Comment: hmmm well in that case it would already be escaped, do you get the error server or client side by the way? I am assuming client but want to make sure.

Comment: Please show the code that sets the value *and* the generated HTML code (as seen in a browser in View Source, for example).

Comment: I just need to know what the correct generated code should be. it seems that &quot; entities are not correct because they actually show up in the textbox text. I'll try the backslash escaping next and see

Comment: I think I found the problem - the html should use the quot entity, but in my case it was being html encoded twice, thus the text box axtually displayed the quot portions.